# Why is this WPF datagrid showing a time when importing data from SQL Server database with date datatype?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, wpfdatagrid

This is what the database data looks like in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

Here it is in design view:

[image]

This is what the datagrid looks like:

[image]

This is the code that I am using to import the data from SQL Server into the datagrid.

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TheatreDatabase2.0;Integrated Security=True");
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM performanceTable", connection);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(data);
            dgdPerformance.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

I am wondering why there is the "12:00:00 AM" at the end of each date in the datagrid and how I would go about removing it.

Comment: The data grid thinks it's a datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses default `DateTime` representation, which in your system, comes from your thread current culture.

If you want to change it, you should derive your columns manually (use DataGridTemplateColumn, and use this in your `CellTemplate`):

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding Path=DateTimeValue, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

C# does not have only `Date` datatype, so when you read data which are of type `Date` from database, it will be converted to `DateTime` in C#.
You can use `StringFormat` to hide the time part.